# Not sure if there's a pest in my soil!

Tags: soil, pests, containers, potting-soil

I had potted some garlic to grow recently, and yesterday when I lifted the pot to clean under it, the soil seemed to look like pest excrement, of some sort. Here is a picture. Can someone help me understand what this is and if I need to be concerned?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLW3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

They might be worm castings. They look similar to the ones in [this picture](https://www.pinterest.at/pin/487303622159324111/). Maybe check the soil to see if you can find any worms, if you're concerned. They shouldn't harm the plants.

Alternatively, they could be from caterpillars, but it looks a little wet for caterpillars to want to venture there.